# Drag and zoom image within bounding box

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-safari, hammer.js

I'm trying to replicate pinch and drag on an image in a mobile web browser.  I can do this with hammerjs, but I am not able to figure out how to keep the image in the bounding container.  For example, if you are zoomed in really far, you should be able to pan but never pan so that there is empty space between the left edge of the image and the left edge of the bounding container.

Imgur does it well, but their code isn't open source.  Any ideas how they accomplish this?  http://m.imgur.com/gallery/LlJr8FA (zoom on the image and pan around, it always stays contained)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

The HTML/CSS

```
<div id="my-mask" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden;">
   <img id="my-image" src="big-image.jpg" width="1000" height="1000"/>
</div>
```

The jQuery/JavaScript

```
// Make sure it always starts @ zero position for below calcs to work
$("#my-image").css({top: 0, left: 0});

var maskWidth  = $("#my-mask").width();
var maskHeight = $("#my-mask").height();
var imgPos     = $("#my-image").offset();
var imgWidth   = $("#my-image").width();
var imgHeight  = $("#my-image").height();

var x1 = (imgPos.left + maskWidth) - imgWidth;
var y1 = (imgPos.top + maskHeight) - imgHeight;
var x2 = imgPos.left;
var y2 = imgPos.top;

$("#my-image").draggable({ containment: [x1,y1,x2,y2] });
$("#my-image").css({cursor: 'move'});
```

Source: [Drag a zoomed image within a div clipping mask using jQuery draggable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590840/drag-a-zoomed-image-within-a-div-clipping-mask-using-jquery-draggable) This has some other stuff that might help you too.

Comment: Thanks but this uses jquery ui which i would like to avoid using.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is late, but for anybody looking for the no jquery-ui solution,
this jquery plugin should solve your problem.

http://plugins.jquery.com/cropbox/

Quote form its description :

> jQuery plugin for in-place image cropping (zoom & pan, as opposed to select and drag). This plugin depends only on jQuery. If either `Hammer.js` or `jquery.hammer.js` is loaded, the cropbox plugin will support gestures for panning and zooming the cropbox.